# Using an Array to make another Array in reverse order

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

really need some help here. My testList is an array[26] of the alphabet. I wanted to use a loop to do a reverse order for newList.

When I test the output of the newList inside the loop it works, but if I test it outside the loop doesn't.  It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me out!

Thanks in advance.

```
 void CText::createList(){
        int i;
        int j;

        for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            counter = 0;
            j = 25; 
            newList[j] = textList[i];
            j--;
           //cout << newList[j] << endl;

        }

        cout << newList[0] << endl;
    }
```

Comment: If you declare `char newList[25]`, then hitting `newList[25]` is out of bounds.

Comment: You should set `j = 25;` just once, before the loop. Closing this as a typo.

Comment: You're tagging as C++ so it's better to use `std::vector`. You can use a reverse iterator in order to obtain what you want.

Comment: It would be much more obvious without pointless `i` and `j` declarations.

Comment: Thanks all, it is all solved. Didn't use Vector because it was just revision question for an upcoming c++ exam and they specifically asked for an array. But Vector seems like a much better approach to things like these. One again thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: If by "testing" you mean printing it outside loop, then you will need a new loop to traverse the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void CText::createList(){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
       newList[25-1-i] = textList[i];
    }
    cout << newList[0] << endl;
}
```

However, it is better to use vector and use reverse iterator for your problem.
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>     
#include <vector>  
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> normal_vector{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::vector<int> reverse_vector(normal_vector.rbegin(),normal_vector.rend());

    for(auto const& item:normal_vector){
        std::cout << item << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
        for(auto const& item:reverse_vector){
        std::cout << item << "\t";
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/662ca)

Comment: The OP says array[25] isn't it `i < 26` undefined behavior?

Comment: Thanks this is a much cleaner code than mine and it works perfect. Additionally LogicStuff's comment of moving the j = 25 outside the loop also works thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `algorithm` header file algorithm `reverse` to do the same

```
void CText::createList() {
    std::copy(textList, textList + 26, newList);
    std::reverse(newList, newList + 26);
    std::cout << newList[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You were reinitializing `j` within the loop, so it was always saving the character at the end. Since your cout inside the lop was using this same `j` that was re-initialized it seemed to work. Try this instead:

```
void CText::createList(){

    for (int i = 0, int j = 25; i < 26; i++, j--)
        newList[j] = textList[i];

    cout << newList[0] << endl;
}
```